# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable + iteration as 'A' not A

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to write a program in python3 that locates specific pictures on the screen. The pictures are of letters of the alphabet and I'm trying to write a for-loop to cover all of the letters instead of writing it out each time.

I've managed to make it work for individual of letters but when I try to run it through all, it spits out the error

> "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Not sure what that means but in addition when attempting to change the file path in each iteration it includes the apostrophes and thus messes up the file path.

THIS WORKS-

```
LETTERSONBOARD = [ ]

Letter_A =(list (pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Letter_A.png'))

LetA = [ ]

for a in Letter_A:

    LetAC.append(pyautogui.center(a))

for a in LetA:

    LETTERSONBOARD.append(a)

print (LetA)
```

THIS DOESN'T-

```
ALPHABET = ['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']

LETTERSONBOARD = []

for xx in ALPHABET:

    Letter_[xx] =(list (pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Letter_'+str[xx]+'.png',))

    Let[xx] = []

    for aa in Letter_[xx]:

        Let[xx].append(pyautogui.center(aa))
    for bb in Let[xx]:

        LETTERSONBOARD.append(bb)

    print (Let[xx])
```

Comment: What are you intending to do with `str[xx]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` is an indicator that you are trying to use square brackets on an object that doesn't support that. Typically "subscription" is how you access dictionary values.

I can see in your code you use `Letter_[xx]`, but I can't see where you defined `Letter_` as a dictionary. You can try to fix it by adding `Letter_ = {}` before the top loop.

---

A few other hints:

- You are filling up `LETTERSONBOARD`, but you seem to never use it.
- You are creating plenty of lists and dictionaries. Think about what you actually really need. What information are you interested in once the whole code snippet is done running?
- Consider using proper variable names that actually tell you what they contain. This will make your code MUCH easier to understand. Not just to others, but also to yourself.

---

Here's your code rewritten with better structure and variable names. Note that I did not test this.

```
ALPHABET = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
FoundLetter = namedtuple("FoundLetter", ["letter", "center_x", "center_y"])
found_letters = []
for letter in ALPHABET:
  letter_image = "C:\\Users\\Letter_{}.png".format(letter)
  for found_letter in pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(letter_image):
    center = pyautogui.center(found_letter)
    finding = FoundLetter(letter, center.x, center.y)
    found_letters.append(finding)
```

Now `found_letters` contains a list of objects that offer the fields `letter`, `center_x` and `center_y`.

Comment: This is just a part of (what I hope will be) a automated Boggle player.
I want it to locate letters on screen, compare letter locations, if the letters are within a certain distance, create a "word", compare "word" to a dictionary, if it matches, click on letters.
With Letter_[xx], I was trying to replace [xx] with all of the letters of the alphabet. Letter_A, Letter_B,...,Letter_Z.
Sorry if that makes it more confusing.

Comment: @Shoggoth_Hunter I've rewritten your code to be somewhat cleaner. Hope this helps you figure out the rest